# Displaying Multiple Regression Equations

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm, lme4

I have three regressions in one plot that I am trying to display the equation of each for. I've been working off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54097340/determing-slope-of-multiple-lines-in-the-same-geom-point-graph-in-ggplot2) question to try and do this. However, the filtering doesn't seem to do anything and it displays the same equation 3 times.

The end goal is to compare cpue in relation to veg, while controlling for location (block), and get the slopes/r^2 values for each of the three regression lines.

**Data**

```
cpue<- structure(list(lake = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), veg = c(254.8026498, 219.9422136, 450.9662078, 484.8605026, 
407.1662151, 286.7015617, 351.6441798, 179.9959443, 340.4276843, 
247.2907435, 502.4119071, 336.4259995, 349.1543197, 281.7493811, 
201.8284859, 325.6380404, 288.3855723, 230.8755861, 214.8890894, 
326.6376698, 214.7468224, 132.0511504, 335.2727641, 336.8727253, 
143.8923225, 277.3053436, 302.7005649, 355.0332852, 307.5736711, 
371.8407176, 168.7645221, 365.9156811, 349.205548, 273.8392697, 
171.4513348, 197.1067049, 350.5833827, 202.9605797, 365.3415045, 
413.2762633, 329.8539209, 377.1415341, 180.8524994, 217.4007852, 
258.5909286, 146.7092479, 258.7440138, 393.2014549, 492.6719497, 
208.5002392, 219.1466664, 182.1366352, 308.0534171, 317.6037795, 
131.7534807, 324.0011761, 469.5861988, 237.4492916, 318.6897863, 
47.94967582, 223.5382632, 386.2227607, 343.7657123, 493.6393726, 
204.2960349, 294.4218332, 178.7555635, 454.0358039, 207.1363947, 
364.6063223, 462.8508521, 292.8613255, 330.3893897, 209.1769838, 
237.4264742, 427.8856667), cpue = c(32.63512612, 47.98168449, 
33.26735173, 14.41435377, 30.94664495, 40.26817963, 41.26204388, 
31.63227286, 36.97932408, 21.54620143, 34.27556883, 6.506644061, 
32.24677471, 38.24536746, 30.95968644, 24.86408391, 31.15438304, 
21.69779047, 39.86223079, 27.92263229, 23.55684281, 34.6157024, 
42.06943746, 24.70597527, 28.36396188, 50.34591832, 55.06361184, 
48.69468021, 26.00084784, 44.77320597, 14.56328001, 33.29291085, 
21.55078237, 29.95980975, 40.61006429, 43.46931237, 26.26407484, 
15.87009067, 39.47297313, 20.50811378, 35.66157343, 35.64563497, 
44.47319537, 42.06574907, 40.16356125, 35.57462201, 32.10051291, 
34.1254268, 34.21084448, 28.18410732, 32.11249307, 38.39890418, 
31.24778375, 29.76951583, 41.52508487, 34.48914051, 28.30923803, 
29.33886042, 37.57268795, 59.29849175, 28.9317113, 41.27342427, 
38.44878019, 44.53768204, 44.48611219, 33.15553274, 34.48894561, 
34.86722967, 31.92515626, 50.04825584, 53.67528105, 37.53150868, 
33.16255301, 33.22374846, 28.28172263, 42.5795616), block = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -76L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Code**

```
# Make lm() with blocking variable----------
lm_eqn2 <- function(df2){
  m2 <- lmer(cpue ~ veg + (1|block), cpue);
  eq2 <- substitute(italic(CPUE) == a + b*","~~italic(r)^2~"="~r2, # Write CPUE = a+b, r^2 = x
                   list(a = format(unname(coef(m2)[1]), digits = 4), # define 'a'
                        b = format(unname(coef(m2)[2]), digits = 2), # define 'b'
                        r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3))) # define 'r2'
  as.character(as.expression(eq)); # declare expression as a character
}


ggplot(cpue, aes(x=veg, y=cpue, col=block))+
  geom_point()+ 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", show.legend=F, se=F)+
  annotate("text", x=100, y=20, label= lm_eqn2(cpue %>% filter(block==1)), parse=T)+
  annotate("text", x=200, y=30, label= lm_eqn2(cpue %>% filter(block==2)), parse=T)+
  annotate("text", x=300, y=40, label= lm_eqn2(cpue %>% filter(block==3)), parse=T)
```

When I try to view the equation for each line with the following code:

```
lm_eqn2(cpue %>% filter(block==2))
```

it returns the same equation for each blocking number that I filter it by. This makes me think there's something wrong with the code that I made the model and the equation with? The only thing different (that I can tell) from the linked question is that my model has a blocking variable. Not sure if that would actually affect anything though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try with `m2 <- lmer(cpue ~ veg + (1|block), df2);`. You always use the unfiltered dataset `cpue`.

Comment: I did try this, however when trying to plot the regression it returns: "Error: grouping factors must have > 1 sampled level". Looking around for a solution to this now. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here.
Firstly, it isn't good practice to use the same name for the dataframe and a vector within. It makes lines like `lmer(cpue ~ veg + (1|block), cpue);` and `ggplot(cpue, aes(x=veg, y=cpue, col=block))+` confusing to many.

But also, using `cpue` here for the dataframe *within your function*, means that your function doesn't care what you are passing to it later. Such that `m2 <- lmer(cpue ~ veg + (1|block), cpue);` is the same every time - hence the same equation is being produced. `cpue %>% filter(block==2)` is ignored as an argument because `df2` doesn't exist within your function. So you need something like this:

```
lm_eqn2 <- function(df2){
  m2 <- lmer(cpue ~ veg + (1|block), df2); ## note the change to df2 here
  eq2 <- substitute(italic(CPUE) == a + b*","~~italic(r)^2~"="~r2, 
                    list(a = format(unname(coef(m2)[1]), digits = 4), 
                         b = format(unname(coef(m2)[2]), digits = 2), 
                         r2 = format(summary(m2)$r.squared, digits = 3))) 
  as.character(as.expression(eq2)); 
}
```

** also note that `m` and `eq` were not found (in your original code), so I changed them to `m2` and `eq2` respectively.

This gives the error:

```
 Error: grouping factors must have > 1 sampled level
```

which makes sense, because you've fit `block` as a random intercept in your model code, yet you are filtering your data *by* the blocking factor. So there is only one "type" of blocking factor in each of the lines `cpue %>% filter(block==1)`, `cpue %>% filter(block==2)`, and `cpue %>% filter(block==3)`. That means there is no information added to your regression when you use `(1|block)`, since `block` is now a constant.

You might want to explain what you are hoping to do with this blocking factor. Some relevant posts: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4700/238878 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/31569/238878

Comment: My blocking factor just represents different lakes that each survey site is located in. So block 1, 2, and 3 represent lake #1, lake #2, and lake #3. And each row represents a different survey site (block/lake 1 has 25 sites, block 2 has 22 sites, and block 3 has 27 sites. We just want to see the relationship between vegetation and cpue (the variable), while controlling for lake/location. The end goal is to obtain the slope/r^2 for the regression lines for each block/lake

Comment: Okay, but the way you've set up your model is that each lake *has* the same slope for vegetation, just different intercepts. What you are doing when you write `lm_eqn2(cpue %>% filter(block==1))` is you are re-running the model with only data from block == 1, which means the block term is meaningless *within* the model.